# How do I make sense of $\{ n \} \cap n$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been learning set theory, and I've come across an exercise in which I'm trying to prove that $\forall x \forall y x \in y \rightarrow y \neq x$. I want to use the axiom of foundation to prove this, but I'm stuck making sense of that axiom for the base case in which a set contains something like a single integer.

If I have $x=\{ y, 5 \}$ for example, and $y=\{5\}$, the axiom of foundation seems to require that $x\cap5=\emptyset$, but it seems like this set should intersect 5. How do I make sense of this? Is the intersection of a set and an integer just always defined as $\emptyset$? Is it even possible to define the intersection of the set and a non-set member of the set?

Comment: How do you define $5$? It must be a set. In set theory, the standard definition is that $5=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, with $0=\emptyset$, $1=\{0\}$, $2=\{0,1\}$, etc. Under this concrete representation, it should be easy now to verify that $x\cap 5=\emptyset$. Of course, there may be other conventions, but once you fix a specific representation of numbers by sets, you should be able to verify the property you are interested in without difficulties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In axiomatic set theory, everything is a set. In particular the integers. Which sets are the integers may vary, but the standard is to use von Neumann's definition:

- $0=\varnothing$, and
- $n+1=n\cup\{n\}$.

So for example $3=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}=\{0,1,2\}$.

And you don't really need to use a "base" case. Just show that if $x\in y$ and $x=y$ then you can prove the negation of the axiom of foundation.